# How to make a mesh deform accurately along curves?

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves, splines

I started to make a mountain pass based on a real road, but I encountered this problem. It gets better when I drag a curve point before the curve down to hell(see pictures), but that's not a great solution of course. It's made with a curve and array modifier.

[image]

[image]

Is there a easy solution for this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the twist parameter to 'Z-Up':

[image]

You can also manually control the tilt of the curve for each vertex or control point of it in the n-panel:

[image]